# Apple Remote Control options does not appear on Advanced Security Preferences panel

Tags: macos, high-sierra, remote-control

[image: . AO]
As you see here, I can't access any Apple Remote Control on my security preferences
so I'm not able to pair my Apple Remote again. I'm using High Sierra updated. Funny thing it was working previously on the same Mac w/ same config. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What model Mac do you have? And be specific.

Comment: it happens on my iMac late 2015 27" 3,2 GHz Intel Core i5, but also on my MacBook Air ...  it not seems to be hardware related, as I think the option disappeared on both at the same time, maybe after an Apple Update ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iMacs late-2012 and newer, MacBook Air 2010 and newer, Retina MacBook, Mac Pro 2013, and Retina MacBook Pro do not have an infrared receiver. You computer may be one of these models.

Comment: OK, maybe I forgot, and was my late 2009 iMac the last Mac working with The Apple Remote Control. I have just renewed my Mac ...